# Help me find out what this texture mapping technique is called

Tags: texture, webgl

I'm in the process of making a tool that requires rendered texture to follow the contours of a piece of clothing. An example would be this website https://knyttan.com/editor/jumper-editor/. The effect here is achieved by using a colour map:[image]

I looked at the shaders that are used for this and it seems that the texture offset is calculated based on the colour channels from this map.

Now I was wondering if this is a complete bespoke way of doing this, or if this is a known technique and if it is what is it called ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you see in the image called a [UV map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping). That is, it is simply texture coordinates to be looked up encoded in a image. Same thing happens in all texture lookup in 3D there is a underlying sampler that picks where to pick texture color from.

[image]

**Image 1**: Image showing UV map of two overlapped triangles and sampled texture with same UV coords

Here are the sources for those images, please do not overwrite the sources.

- [Demo](http://webglplayground.net/saved/CZTXXQeZFH) showing the UV map
- [Demo](http://webglplayground.net/saved/tTnh7zvUc6) showing the texture